# Open Office just doesn't work now

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

All items worked, I needed some font management so I was successful in loading font manager, then I went to open write, and it wasn't there, or any of the open office suite... tried to then remove it, and get it and install it again like I had done. Now the icons are back, yet they do nothing. I then tried removing open office multiple times and the icons are still there,... Any ideas? Do I have to remove Font manager, and go back to having only 5 fonts? Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you try and open the icon for it? Does it give any sort of error or does it just do nothing? Please put this info into your question so we can help more.

Comment: Thanks, it does nothing when clicking from the launcher. When clicking the icon from the filefolder it closes the folder view, yet that is all that happens, just back to the desktop.

Comment: Have you checked the active processes before and after you clicked the icon to see if it added a ghost process?

Comment: No, how do i do that, and what is a ghost process?

Comment: What I mean by a ghost process is that the process would be running in the background and not properly, but it is technically starting something. You can check the process list by typing `top` which displays a live organized list of running processes.

Comment: Thank you Owen! I will try that later today., and if it IS starting (something) I guess it needs to be removed? AS I said I will look later today. Thank you

Comment: I did get launch the terminal and typed top, it showed 0zombies, I am guessing that is what I was looking for. Also, when I did try to launch openoffice writer from the launcher while observing the terminal, I saw nothing of a pattern (while clicking multiple times), Like I mentioned nothing appears to happen or change. I am not sure what to do, as I have already tried to remove it, as well as it DID actually work, and yet appeared to stop functioning after installing fontmanager... any ideas? Or how I can remove it completely and perhaps try Libreoffice,

Comment: Anyone? As I said tried to remove it and start again, that didn't work either. Should I now try to remove fontmanager as the variable in openoffice dying? Thanks for any input...